# Seamless UV Texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm creating a model of a road to use in Unity. The edges need to be able to tile so I can link multiple parts together. I made a UV map and edited it in Gimp. I used the seamless filter in gimp to make the top part of the road seamless, however I'm still getting a line on the very edge. Any ideas on how I can make a better texture for this?

Unity
[image]

Blender

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Unless you are asking how to make a seamless texture within blender, this question appears to be off-topic because it is not about blender (It's about gimp or any image manipulation program capable of making textures). You might want to try asking over on [GraphicDesign](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks! I asked this on the Unity stack exchange too and also got told it was not relevant so I'll try over on graphic design!

Answer (score 1):

Split your view, so that you can have 3dview and UV Window.
Select Texture Paint in 3d view.
In Uv window, Turn on N Panel and in Display check Repeat.
This alows you to tile your texture.

Now in 3dview, select Clone tool. Choose a point in your textures, which you want to clone. Left click to move the curson at chosen point (Ctrl+Left CLick)  and start cloning your texture to seamless one.

Move your UV layout in uv window, when you want to offset the texture.
[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? [What I got](http://puu.sh/6BGvT.png)

Comment: ohh. it seems that your uv map is not layed out correct.
Seamless only work with properly layed out UVs.